# Corresponding Index Into Parallel Array

Tags: handlebars.js

In **Handlebars.js**, how can I use `@index` to subscript into another parallel array in the object I am passing to a template?

For example, say I have an object set up like the following:

```
var table = {
    cols : [
        { name: "Column 1" },
        { name: "Column 2" },
        { name: "Column 3", highlighted: true }
    ],
    rows : [
        {
            label: "Row 1",
            data: [
                { val: 5 },
                { val: 3 },
                { val: 8 }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: "Row 2",
            data: [
                { val: 8 },
                { val: 4 },
                { val: 0 }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I need to be able to use the `@index` from an `{{#each rows}}{{#each data}}` loop to check if the column is highlighted to apply a style to cells in the column, but **Handlebars.js** does not appear to allow using `@index` in a subscript operator.

E.g.

```
{{@index}} <!-- Index of current rows.data is 2. -->

{{#if ../../cols.[@index].highlighted }}
    <!-- Never Executed -->
{{/if}}

{{#if ../../cols.[2].highlighted }}
    <!-- Executes -->
{{/if}}
```

Is this not supported? Am I doing something wrong? How can I get this to work easily?

I posted an [example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/corymcd/UMMVa/).

Comment: FYI `{{#if ../../cols.@index.highlighted }}` does not work either, causing the parse error `Expecting 'ID', got 'DATA'`.

Comment: Why don't you do the data wrangling in JavaScript instead? Handlebars templates are meant to be very light on the logic after all.

Comment: So you're suggesting something like adding a `highlighted: true` to each column cell that should be highlighted? I guess I can do that, but it seemed like unnecessary duplication of data.

Comment: I'm suggesting that you pre-digest your data for the template. You don't have to store the pre-digested data, just set it up, hand it to the compiled template function, and throw it away. You could also unroll `cols` to make it easier to access the currently hilighted column in Handlebars.

Comment: @muistooshort I don't understand what you're saying, but this is leading to the much-frowned-upon discussion. Should I create a different question asking specifically about highlighting a column in a Handlebars template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@key` and `@index` behave specially, not as variables. So, even when you can use `myvar.[123]` you cannot use `myvar.[@key]` even though `@key` is 123. (At least, as of Handlebars 1.3.0)

There are two solutions. The first is to write your own handlebars helper, that takes both arrays/objects. The second is to restructure your data, i.e. merge your two parallel arrays.

As an example of the latter approach, if you have these two arrays:

```
var X={
  cat:"meow",
  sheep:"baaa"
  };
var Y={
  cat:3,
  sheep:5
  };
```

Then you could do:

```
var Z={};
for(var ix in X){
  Z[ix]={X:X[ix],Y:Y[ix]};
  }
```

And then pass `Z` to your handlebars template:

```
myTemplate({animals:Z});
```

which might look like this:

```
{{#each animals}}
  The {{@key}} goes {{this.X}}; we have {{this.Y}} of them.
{{/each}}
```